# Span tag height is not adjusted to child input tag

Tags: input, height, width, html

Hi,

I have a input tag which is in span.I want to style that span setting border and box-shadow and for input tag border:none. The problem is, It looks,the height of the input is more than  span tag,so if I put border to span, its not shown,since it is covered by input tag.

I believe that, If a element is put inside span tag, then span tag width and height must be adjusted to child tag height and width.But that's not happening here.

Here is my code..What could be wrong....

Note:In this code, I didnt put border:none for input tag,to make visible what actually the problem is...!!!

```
 <style>
  body{
   font-family:Arial,Tahoma,sans-serif;
   font-size:0.7em;
  }
  span{
  border:1px solid blue;
  box-shadow:3px 3px 3px #888;
  }
   input {
   font-size:100%;
   }
  </style>

 <body>

  <span>
    <input type="text"/>
  </span>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you could use the css and html like this:

```
 <style>
  body{
   font-family:Arial,Tahoma,sans-serif;
   font-size:0.7em;
  }
   input {
   font-size:100%;
   border:1px solid blue;
   box-shadow:3px 3px 3px #888;
   }
  </style>

 <body>

    <input type="text"/>
 </body>
```

Just put the border and box-shadow into the input-tag and you could remove the span-tag.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..Yes,I have an idea abt that logic,But in my case input box must be wrapped with span tag.That is my requirement..May know the reason,why that span height is not adjusted to child element..!!!

Comment: Okay... i think, span doesn't render any height oder width by default. i had the same problem too. try to set into the span definition in css this: "display: block;"

Comment: I put display:block,height is ok now,but width is set to body width..The width must be as much as of chlild's too...Can I achieve this too??

Comment: Okay, i see! Please try:   "display: inline-block;" now you can use height and width in span :-)